How do I join filter strings into a url string?
I am building a URL query, that allows the filtering of multiple fields. The filtering (e.g. from a form) is stored as pair values: column and FILTER. I am storing the filters as a list of pairs.
I want to join a list of paired values (column, FILTER) into a url string.
Sample:
"$filter=contains(column1%2C%27FILTER1%27)+and+contains(column2%2C%27FILTER2%27)+and+contains(column3..."

filter_lists = [['level', 'FIRST'], ['name', 'OFFICE'], ['number', 'FIVE']]
filter1 = f"contains({filter_lists[0][0]}%2C%27{filter_lists[0][1]}%27)"
filter_rest = [[f"+and+contains({item}%2C%27" for item in filter_lists[1:]] for subitem in filter_lists[0]][0]

filter_all = "".join(filter_rest)
url_str = f"$filter={filter1}{filter_all}"

url_str returns:
"$filter=contains(level%2C%27FIRST%27)+and+contains(['name', 'OFFICE']%2C%27+and+contains(['number', 'FIVE']%2C%27"

desired string:
"$filter=contains(level%2C%27FIRST%27)+and+contains(name%2C%27OFFICE%27)+and+contains(number%2C%27FIVE%27)"

Is there a simpler way instead of storing the columns and filters in a list[list]?

Simple one-liner: url_str = f"$filter={'+and+'.join(f'contains({c}%2C%27{v}%27)' for c, v in filter_lists)}".

filter_lists = [['level', 'FIRST'], ['name', 'OFFICE'], ['number', 'FIVE']]
filter1 = f"contains({filter_lists[0][0]}%2C%27{filter_lists[0][1]}%27)"
filter_rest = [[f"+and+contains({item[0]}%2C%27{item[1]}%27)" for item in filter_lists[1:]] for subitem in filter_lists[0]][0]

filter_all = "".join(filter_rest)
url_str = f"$filter={filter1}{filter_all}"

returns:
$filter=contains(level%2C%27FIRST%27)+and+contains(name%2C%27OFFICE%27)+and+contains(number%2C%27FIVE%27)

markus1998, thanks for your code sample! Would you consider adding a little more explanation for what it does/how it works? This will help both the original asker and anyone who comes across this post understand the concepts and tools behind it.

filter_template = "contains({}%2C%27{}%27)"
filter_conditions = [["level", "FIRST"], ["name", "OFFICE"], ["number", "FIVE"]]
formatted_filters = [filter_template.format(f, v) for f, v in filter_conditions]
filter_query = "$filter=" + "+and+".join(formatted_filters)

Output:
"$filter=contains(level%2C%27FIRST%27)+and+contains(name%2C%27OFFICE%27)+and+contains(number%2C%27FIVE%27)"


e-motta, thanks for your code sample! Would you consider adding a little more explanation for what it does/how it works? This will help both the original asker and anyone who comes across this post understand the concepts and tools behind it.

To keep the strings more readable try to make a kind of template by using {} as placeholder in a string and evaluate them with format. See here for deeper explanations and examples of usage and below a possible solution.
filter1 = "contains({}%2C%27{}%27)".format(*filter_lists[0])

filter_template = "+and+contains({}%2C%27{}%27)"
filter_rest = (filter_template + filter_template).format(*filter_lists[1], *filter_lists[2])

url_str = f"$filter={filter1}{filter_rest}"

